# Correct way to dispatch redux action from request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

I am using redux-thunk and I have the following action:

```
export const fetchUserInfo = () => dispatch => {
  return fetchCurrentUser()
    .then(user => {
      dispatch(retrieveUser(user));

      if (user && user.settings && user.settings.storePageId) {
        dispatch(getStoreById(user.settings.storePageId));
      }

      return user;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Fetching userinfo failed', err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

fetchCurrentUser is an api call defined as such:

```
export const fetchCurrentUser = () => authenticatedRequest('/customer');
```

Here is my authenticatedRequest:

```
import { logoutUser } from '../../actions/auth';
export const authenticatedRequest = (url, opts = {}, req = request) => {
  if (!cachedTokenType || !cachedAccessToken) {
    logoutUser() // I want this to happen!! :(

    return Promise.reject(
      new Error(
        'Missing token_type & access_token needed to perform this request'
      )
    );
  }

  const headers = { ...defaultOpts.headers, ...(opts.headers || {}) };

  const authedOpts = {
    ...opts,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: `${cachedTokenType} ${cachedAccessToken}`
    }
  };

  return req(url, authedOpts);
};
```

I want to be able to dispatch logoutUser() in my authenticatedRequest func so I dont have to duplicate this logic at all the places using authenticatedRequest. My problem is I dont know how to call a redux action from another file and when not in a react component with connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I want to be able to dispatch logoutUser() in my authenticatedRequest func...`

I'd say that by achieving that, `authenticatedRequest` is doing more than one thing (authenticating and possibly logging users out). With time, complexity might increase and gets worst in case you want to change `redux-thunk` to something else.

Should you still need it, you can propagate `dispatch` so you can dispatch other actions:

```
const fetchCurrentUser = (dispatch) => authenticatedRequest(dispatch, '/customer')

const authenticatedRequest = (dispatch, url, opts = {}, req = request) => {
  if (YOUR_CONDITION) {
    dispatch(logoutUser())
  }
  ...
}
```

I personally wouldn't do that since it exposes `dispatch` to external calls.
It's your choice though :)

Is it possible to handle `logoutUser` in `fetchUserInfo` action?

```
const authenticatedRequest = (url, opts = {}, req = request) => {
  if (YOUR_CONDITION) {
    return Promise.reject('LOGOUT')
  }
  ...
}

const fetchUserInfo = () => dispatch => {
  return fetchCurrentUser()
    .then(user => {
      ...
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err === 'LOGOUT') {
        dispatch(logoutUser())
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: by not doing it in authenticated request I will need to write logic for logging out on all actions using authenticatedRequest and if one coworker forgets to fallback to it we got inconsistant token expiration. Thanks for your help, I will try your code :=)

Comment: What do you think about a middleware that checks the token on all actions?